# How to set a custom position for masks in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, vector-graphics

I'm trying set a custom position for an SVG mask in Firefox, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. The docs on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask are pretty incomplete (and yes, I know this isn't standarized, but still...).

On Chrome/Safari, using the shorthand "url(mask.svg) xposition yposition / size;" does the trick, but on Firefox it just won't work as it is recognized as an invalid property value.

Here's a dabblet of what I've done so far http://dabblet.com/gist/83bf9a8708193634892e.
As you can see, when using Chrome/Safari everything's correct but on Firefox the mask is mispositioned.

Is there a way to set a position to the mask or is this unsupported on Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a translate to the path element e.g. `transform="translate(150,100)"`

Firefox supports the [SVG 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#Masking) with regards to masks. It does not (yet) support CSS masking, except for those parts of CSS Masking that happen to coincide with SVG 1.1

Comment: Again, thanks a ton!
I was able to vertically and horizontally center the path using javascript-calculated values and the transform attribute.